# Hibernate query "or condition" won't work

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I am trying the following hibernate query but it always gives me a wrong result:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Jcelulasmin> getAllOthers(int id, String username) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Jcelulasmin> JcelulasList = session.createQuery("from Jcelulasmin where jgrelhas.id=? and (jconcorrentes is null or jconcorrentes.users.username <> ?) order by id").setParameter(0, id).setString(1, username).list();
        for(Jcelulasmin p : JcelulasList){
            logger.info("Jcelulas List::"+p);
        }
        return JcelulasList;
    }
```

This query returns me 13 values, but that should be the result of "jconcorrentes.users.username <> ?"

The result of "jconcorrentes is null" is 47 values so my query should return 47+13=60...

I'm trying to achieve the following SQL query that actually returns 60 values:

```
SELECT * FROM `jcelulas` WHERE GrelhasId=1 and (ConcorrentesId is null or ConcorrentesId<>1)
```

ps:jconcorrentes.id is 1 so the sql and hql should be the same

Table/Entitiy definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jconcorrentes", catalog = "7jogos")
public class Jconcorrentes implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    ....
    private Users users;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Users getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
```

I tried the following and it actually worked:

```
session.createQuery("from Jcelulasmin where jgrelhas.id=? and (jconcorrentes is null or jconcorrentes <> 1) order by id").setParameter(0, id).list();
```

The only problem is that i have to get it by username which is in Users.

Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "7jogos", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"))
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

@NotEmpty(message="Não se esqueça do Email")
@Email(message="Email Inválido")
private String username;
...
private Set<Jconcorrentes> jconcorrenteses = new HashSet<Jconcorrentes>(0);


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "users")
    public Set<Jconcorrentes> getJconcorrenteses() {
    return this.jconcorrenteses;
}

public void setJconcorrenteses(Set<Jconcorrentes> jconcorrenteses) {
    this.jconcorrenteses = jconcorrenteses;
}
```

Comment: is that username actually returning the id 1 though? try replacing jconcorrentes.users.username <> ? with ConcorrentesId<>1

Comment: Also this: ConcorrentesId is null or ConcorrentesId<>1
is the same as: ConcorrentesId<>1, because NULL isn't equal to 1, unless you were trying to say IS NOT NULL but that would probably give you even less rows which isn't the problem I guess

Comment: @JeremyC. Executing each query at a time it gives the expected answers but using the or condition it wont work. And yes i have checked it

Comment: Can you add your table definitions in the question so I can get a better idea of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but jconcorrentes.users.username <> ? doesn't return me the values of where jconcorrentes is null

Comment: Well your current query and what you are trying to do are using different columns so I don't know exactly what you are trying to do if I don't see your tables

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that Jcelulasmin is same as jcelulas in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query translates to inner join between Jcelulasmin and jconcorrentes (because of `jconcorrentes.users.username`), thus nulls are excluded. You have to explicitly left join them:

```
select j from Jcelulasmin j left join j.jconcorrentes jcon ...
```

Comment: Thanks i think it's the correct reason why this is happening but i have moved to a different approach so i can't really test your answer in hql

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of `jconcorrentes is null`, you should try something like `jconcorrentes.id <> 1`.

Comment: please put tables and entities in the question

Comment: i just added the entities

Comment: I dont have any id mapped in Users entity but my@Id is username and i have already tried it but i get the same result as jconcorrentes.users.username <> ?

Comment: In sql you did not use username:
SELECT * FROM `jcelulas` WHERE GrelhasId=1 and (ConcorrentesId is null or ConcorrentesId<>1) 

try like this in hql:
jconcorrentes is null or jconcorrentes.id <> 1

Comment: I tried it and it did return the correct values as i mention in the question (edited)